# How IOCTL works?

Tags: windows, kernel, ioctl, deviceiocontrol

I want to know how IOCTL works.
I know the basics:

DeviceIoControl() -> kernel32.dll -> ntdll.dll -> the moment it gets from user mode to kernel mode -> I/O Manager -> IRP

Question is how IOCTL gets form user mode to the kernel mode? Is it interrupt gate, call gate, or something else?

If you know any article/book that explains details of IOCTL (more than Windows Internals) please post a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `DeviceIoControl` in `Kernel32.dll` you'll see it calls `NtDeviceIoControlFile` from `ntdll.dll`.  This in turn does a `syscall` which does the transition from user-mode to kernel-mode.

Comment: To be more specific, it loads the system call and return address onto the stack then calls `kifastsystemcall` which then loads a secret number (giving kernel mode access) and makes the `syscall`, and then `kifastsystemcallret` is used with the return address parameter.  Therefore a user wanting to go this low-level will need to use `kifastsystemcall`.